# How to add the two variations of the open syscall in OS161?

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel, mips, system-calls

From the man pages of `OS161`:

### **Synopsis**

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int
open(const char *filename, int flags);
int
open(const char *filename, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

---

How the standard c library function `open` is defined:

```
int open(const char *filename, int flags, ...);
```

The declaration:

```
/*
 * Definition for each syscall.
 * All we do is load the syscall number into v0, the register the
 * kernel expects to find it in, and jump to the shared syscall code.
 * (Note that the addiu instruction is in the jump's delay slot.)
 */

#define SYS_open         45

#define SYSCALL(sym, num) \
   .set noreorder       ; \
   .globl sym           ; \
   .type sym,@function      ; \
   .ent sym         ; \
sym:                ; \
   j __syscall                  ; \
   addiu v0, $0, SYS_##sym  ; \
   .end sym         ; \
   .set reorder

SYSCALL(open, 45)
```

---

When a syscall is issued, a syscall dispatcher is called. The syscall dispatcher takes a pointer to a `trapframe` which includes the values of registers before the syscall is issued. One of the registers contains the syscall number, which the dispatcher uses to dispatch to the right syscall function. The dispatcher looks like this:

```
void
syscall(struct trapframe *tf)
{
    int callno;

    ...

    callno = tf->tf_v0;

    ...

    switch (callno) {
        case SYS_reboot:
        err = sys_reboot(tf->tf_a0);
        break;

        case SYS___time:
        err = sys___time((userptr_t)tf->tf_a0,
                 (userptr_t)tf->tf_a1);

    ...

}
```

Here is a comment that describes how arguments are passed and how to return values:

```
 * The calling conventions for syscalls are as follows: Like ordinary
 * function calls, the first 4 32-bit arguments are passed in the 4
 * argument registers a0-a3. 64-bit arguments are passed in *aligned*
 * pairs of registers, that is, either a0/a1 or a2/a3. This means that
 * if the first argument is 32-bit and the second is 64-bit, a1 is
 * unused.
 *
 * This much is the same as the calling conventions for ordinary
 * function calls. In addition, the system call number is passed in
 * the v0 register.
 *
 * On successful return, the return value is passed back in the v0
 * register, or v0 and v1 if 64-bit. This is also like an ordinary
 * function call, and additionally the a3 register is also set to 0 to
 * indicate success.
 *
 * On an error return, the error code is passed back in the v0
 * register, and the a3 register is set to 1 to indicate failure.
 * (Userlevel code takes care of storing the error code in errno and
 * returning the value -1 from the actual userlevel syscall function.
 * See src/user/lib/libc/arch/mips/syscalls-mips.S and related files.)
```

You can see that for example `sys_reboot` is called with `tf->tf_a0`, That's because before the syscall is issued, the register `a0` contained the first (and only) parameter for the syscall.

I'm not gonna dive into details for simplicity and because it's probably irrelevant. For example, the process of issuing a syscall is a bit more complicated, but I've mentioned only the relevant stuff. Also not gonna talk about how to get arguments off the stack since I'll not need it here.

---

I'm supposed to implement the `sys_open` syscall, but I'm not sure how to know which variant of the `open` functions has been called...

All I have is the syscall number and the values of the registers, which includes the four arguments registers, the stack pointer and the other registers.

How can I determine whether I'm facing the first variation (with only two parameters) or the second one (with 3 parameters) so that I can behave accordingly?

---

### Some useful information:

The whole code for syscall is [here](https://github.com/ops-class/os161/blob/master/kern/arch/mips/syscall/syscall.c#L79).

The whole repo for OS161 is [here](https://github.com/ops-class/os161).

The exception handler code is loaded into memory during the boot here.

The code for the exception handler (the first code that runs when a syscall is issued) is [here](https://github.com/ops-class/os161/blob/master/kern/arch/sys161/main/start.S#L131).

The exception handler is a function called `mips_general_handler` that just calls a function `common_exception`.

`mips_general_handler` is [here](https://github.com/ops-class/os161/blob/master/kern/arch/mips/locore/exception-mips1.S#L86).

`common_exception` is [here](https://github.com/ops-class/os161/blob/master/kern/arch/mips/locore/exception-mips1.S#L106).

`common_exception` pushed all the values of the registers onto the stack, also pushes a pointer to the beginning of the pushed values (that's the pointer that's passed to the function being called) and calls the function `mips_trap` which can be found [here](https://github.com/ops-class/os161/blob/master/kern/arch/mips/locore/trap.c#L126).

The function `misp_trap` looks for the cause of the exception, and if it's a syscall, calls the function `syscall` which is given above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, that OS161 man page is **wrong** in incorrectly implying that there are two versions of the `open()` function.  There is only one version of `open()` - C does not support function overloading like that man page implies.  [Per POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/openat.html) the one version of `open()` is

```
SYNOPSIS
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);
```

Note how that man page confused you into thinking there are two versions of `open()`.  There isn't.  That kind of sloppiness is really bad in what's supposed to be a "teaching operating system".

The `mode` argument will be present if the `oflag` argument as the `O_CREAT` bit set:

> `O_CREAT`
>
> If the file exists, this flag has no effect except as noted under
> `O_EXCL` below. Otherwise, if `O_DIRECTORY` is not set the file shall
> be created as a regular file; the user ID of the file shall be set to
> the effective user ID of the process; the group ID of the file shall
> be set to the group ID of the file's parent directory or to the
> effective group ID of the process; and **the access permission bits
> (see `<sys/stat.h>`) of the file mode shall be set to the value of the
> argument following the oflag argument taken as type `mode_t`**
> modified as follows: a bitwise AND is performed on the file-mode bits
> and the corresponding bits in the complement of the process' file mode
> creation mask. Thus, all bits in the file mode whose corresponding bit
> in the file mode creation mask is set are cleared. When bits other
> than the file permission bits are set, the effect is unspecified. The
> argument following the oflag argument does not affect whether the file
> is open for reading, writing, or for both. Implementations shall
> provide a way to initialize the file's group ID to the group ID of the
> parent directory. Implementations may, but need not, provide an
> implementation-defined way to initialize the file's group ID to the
> effective group ID of the calling process.

Assuming for OS161 the `char *path` argument is a 64-bit pointer and both `int` and `mode_t` are 32 bits, the `a0` and `a1` registers should contain the `path` pointer argument, `a2` should contain the `oflag` argument, and `a3` should contain the `mode` argument if the `O_CREAT` bit is set in the `oflag` argument.  If the user-process calling code did not use the `mode` argument but did set the `O_CREAT` bit,

Note that [the Linux `open()` syscall](https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/SysCall/linux-syscall-5.html) is implemented in exactly this way* - the `mode` argument is set by the calling process if it's relevant.

* - Almost.  Linux actually implements `open()` as `openat( AT_FDCWD, ...)`.  If OS161 provides `openat()`, you should probably implement `open()` as `openat( AT_FDCWD, ...)` also.